# How to parse a filter expression and retrieve JSON object using c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

i have a filter expression say 
(username = "john" and phone_number = "00000000000") 
how to parse and evaluate the filter expression and perform a search operation in a json file using c++ and retrieve json object which matches the filter.please give me some idea about how to proceed.

Comment: This is too broad.  What have you got? What have you tried?

Comment: Boost and Qt support JSON serialization and deserialization, then there is jsoncpp which can be used if Boost and Qt are not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/property_tree.html).